# How to change popup title scope variable dynamically when button click in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two popup's having in a single html page, i need to change the popup title based on popup click. I'm using title for $scope variable. I tried the below code but it is not changing the title, please help me on this.

Html:

```
<div id="Popup" title="{{title}}">
  <div data-ng-include src="'Partials/Popup.html'" data-ng-show="newPopup"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.PopupOne = function() {
  $scope.title = 'Popup One'; // I tried this
  $scope.ShowPopup('Popup');
  Factory.HttpRequest('ABC1.ashx', dataJson)
    .success(function(dt) {
        //parameters
      }
    };
}

$scope.PopupTwo = function() {
  $scope.title = 'Popup Two'; //I tried
  $scope.ShowPopup('Popup');
  Factory.HttpRequest('ABC2.ashx', dataJson)
    .success(function(dt) {
        //parameters
      }
    };
}
```

When i click popup button on the popup title is not showing but i can able to see at inspect elements 
[Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLhck.png)

[image]

Comment: did you confirm that the function is called?

Comment: Yes, function's are calling and loading the popup with corresponding data

Comment: can you try setting it in a `$timeout` function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDynamicValue = $scope[title];
$scope.PopupTwo = function () {
    $scope.title = myDynamicValue; //I tried
    $scope.ShowPopup('Popup'); 
    Factory.HttpRequest('ABC2.ashx', dataJson)
        .success(function (dt) {
         //parameters
       } 
};
```